# Unit of least precision without strictfp

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy, numerical-analysis, strictfp

Looking at **Math** class, the [`ulp` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(float)):

```
public static float ulp(float f)
```

If the method is applied like: `Math.ulp(Float.MAX_VALUE)`, then this rule from the Javadoc documentation comes up:

> If the argument is ±Float.MAX_VALUE, then the result is equal to 2<sup>104</sup>.

Can it be ensured from machine to machine that this number (2<sup>104</sup>) will always be that one even if the float is not **strictfp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of `strictfp` doesn't magically make your numbers do weird things.

It just allows platforms with more precision to execute calculations with more precision than the result actually holds (i.e. if you do calculations on `float` then non-`strictfp` code might actually use a 40-bit floating point register for intermediary steps).

This doesn't change the fact that your inputs and outputs that you see in your code will still always be `float`.

In other words: `strictfp` is not a property of a `float` variable or number. It's a property of *code that operates on `float` or `double`*.

In short: yes, if the spec says that this number will be returned, then it will be returned.

Comment: Indeed the strictfp is not doing more than enforce the standard usage. Also, according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html both float and double primitive data types are already IEEE 754 compatible which makes the domain of floating points to return expected and consistent results.